# ActionBar Apptheme Textcolor Issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have created library project ,integrated into another project as SDK,Action Bar Textcolor need to change based on appthem,in my SDK colorprimary takes automatically.

My issue is project will not change colour of text based on apothem for example my collor #8c0bfd action bar textcolor theme would be white but it will display black colour

This is project styles .xml:
        @color/colorPrimary
        @color/colorPrimaryDark
        @color/colorAccent

```
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Actionbar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />



<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

This Library Project styles.xml:
        
        @color/colorPrimary
        @color/colorPrimaryDark
        @color/colorAccent
        @style/AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton

```
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</style>


<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/divider</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/marigintop</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/mariginbottom</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Was just pushed my library project into jcenter and add it as a idk in like dependency in another project

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see what you've already tried

Comment: Instead of `ActionBar` use `Toolbar`.